# CMake vs JNI have different behaviors between VisualStudio and Linux

Tags: java, linux, visual-c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use *CMake* to create a multi-platform project (Windows+VisualStudio AND Linux+gcc) using *jni*.
The issue is that **jni_md.h** is well found with Linux but not in MSVC.
**jni_md.h** is in a platform-dependent subdirectory of the one that contains **jni.h**.

Here is a very minimal extract of my project :
`CMakeLists.txt :`

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.12 )
find_package( JNI 11 REQUIRED )
project( spam )
include_directories( ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( spam main.cpp )
```

`main.cpp :`

```
#include <jni.h>
int main () {}
```

In both worlds, `cmake .` works well.
In Linux world :
The command `cmake . --build` works well, and in the verbose traces of *gcc* I can see these includes :
`-I /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux`. (I wonder how *CMake* find out that it has to add this second path)

But It's getting bad in windows world:
In the Visual Studio solution, I can see that `C:/Programs/jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot/include` is well in the *properties/include directories*, but not `C:/Programs/jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot/include/win32` (which contains **jni_md.h**).
And, no surprise, the command `cmake --build .` fails:

```
  Building Custom Rule CMakeLists.txt
  include
c1xx : fatal error C1083: 'C:/Programs/jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot/include' : No such file or directory [spam.vcxproj]
  main.cpp
C:\Programs\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot\include\jni.h(45): fatal error C1083: 'jni_md.h' : No such file or directory
```

By the way, `C:/Programs/jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot/include` and `C:/Programs/jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot/include/win32` actually exists.

How to make it properly work in both worlds ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindJNI apparently makes a distinction between platforms that need jni_md.h and those that doesn't. In your case it arrived at the wrong conclusion.
Still, it should have calculated the path and put it in the `JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2` variable. On other platforms that is folded into the `JNI_INCLUDE_DIR` variable so adding it again as an include directory is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to ***Botje***, the proper solution is to use the variable *JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2* (which seems to be set at the same time that *JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS*).
Just edit the *CMakeLists.txt* like this :

```
include_directories( ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2} )
```

It works fine in the both worlds !